# Getting NetBeans' C++ parser to work with Emscripten

Tags: c++, netbeans, emscripten

I'm having a little problem with NetBeans' C++ parser. Everything seems to work fine except for when I do `std::vector` or `std::cout` etc. in my code. If I leave off the `std::` part the parser works fine but when I have it in it gives

```
"Unable to resolve identifier vector."
```

(or `cout` in the other example). Anyone know why it's doing this?

Additional Info:

I'm using Netbean 8. I have the following settings in *Tools > Options > C/C++ > Build Tools*:

```
Build Host:       Localhost
Family:           CLang
Encoding:         UTF-8

Base Directory:   C:\Program Files\Emscripten
C Compiler:       C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.12.0\emcc
C++ Compiler:     C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.12.0\em++
Debugger Command: C:\Program Files\Emscripten\mingw\4.6.2_32bit\gdb.exe
CMake Command:    C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe
```

I have the following include paths in *Tools > Options > C/C++ > Code Assistance > C++ Compiler > Include Directories*:

```
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.12.0\system\include
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.12.0\system\include\libc
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.12.0\system\include\emscripten
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.12.0\system\include\libcxx
```

Edit:

I figured out the likely cause of the problem. It seems that some LLVM/CLang  libraries use definitions `_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD` and `_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD` *(contained in `<__config>`)* instead of `namespace std;` for some libraries including `<iostream>` and `<vector>` and I'm guessing those are hidden from Netbeans C++ parser.

I'm not sure how to fix this yet. Will report back if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the entry:

```
__clang__
```

in *Tools > Options > C/C++ > Code Assistance > C++ Compiler > Macro Definitions*.

This made `_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD` and `_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD` visible to Netbeans' parser and in-turn showed it that `vector` and `cout` were in the `std` namespace.